# Flowrouter reset password route not rendering

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I'm trying to setup the reset password route however there appears to be something wrong with the route and I'm not sure what it is.

**email link**

```
http://localhost:3000/reset-password/MKlpo8uJVAsZ5P_UnU1yUHi_4Ez2csh0DtEo4umazwU
```

Path: `routes.js`

```
    FlowRouter.route( '/reset-password/:token', {
  name: 'atResetPwd',
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render('loginTemplates', {
      navbar: 'navbar',
      content: 'atResetPwd',
      footer: 'footer'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate "there appears to be something wrong".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not passing the token to your route, so it's not available to your functions.

```
    FlowRouter.route( '/reset-password/:token', {
  name: 'atResetPwd',
  action: function(params) {
    BlazeLayout.render('loginTemplates', {
      navbar: 'navbar',
      content: 'atResetPwd',
      footer: 'footer'
    });
  }
});
```

Then you can try to retrieve the token from your client side code, to call the appropriate method.